# How to use Azure Function filtering with FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute in .Net 5

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

According to this [article](https://philippbauknecht.medium.com/authentication-authorization-in-azure-functions-with-azure-active-directory-using-c-net-aad52c8de925), Azure Functions can have an attribute that is triggered by the execution of the function:

```
internal class AuthorizeAttribute : FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnExecutingAsync(FunctionExecutingContext executingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var request = (HttpRequest)executingContext.Arguments["req"];
        var user = await AuthorizationHandler.ValidateRequestAsync(request, executingContext.Logger);

        if (user != null)
        {
            request.HttpContext.User.AddIdentities(user.Identities);
        }
        else
        {
            request.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            await request.HttpContext.Response.Body.FlushAsync();
            request.HttpContext.Response.Body.Close();
    

    throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
}



[Authorize]
[FunctionName("SampleFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "sample")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log, ClaimsPrincipal user)
{
  ...
}
```

This could allow us to create some security check before the function is executed.

Unfortunately all the examples are for Azure Functions v1-v3 and uses a different syntax.

The new Functions syntax is somewhat different:

```
[Authorize]
[Function("GetData")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> GetData(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "data1")] HttpRequestData req,
     FunctionContext executionContext, ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{
  ...
}
```

Using `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker` functions, ***the attribute is not triggered***.

Can you give me some hint of how to modify the code to create a pre-execution check?

Comment: You can check [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#middleware) to achieve it. It would be equivalent how things are configured in ASP.Net core.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [user1672994](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672994/user1672994). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

.NET isolated also supports middleware registration, again by using a model similar to what exists in ASP.NET.

The [ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.workerhostbuilderextensions.configurefunctionsworkerdefaults?view=azure-dotnet&preserve-view=true#Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_WorkerHostBuilderExtensions_ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults_Microsoft_Extensions_Hosting_IHostBuilder_) extension method has an overload that lets you register your own middleware.

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(workerApplication =>
    {
        // Register our custom middleware with the worker
        workerApplication.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();
    })
    .Build();
```

Comment: Middleware is called for absolutely every function you have in the function host, I believe the original post was alluding to functionality akin to ASP.NET's Filters which are called once per request to which they're associated.

Comment: Middleware can be executed conditionally, using `UseWhen` [middleware registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#middleware).